# Laravel nested route group inverse middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, middleware

I have a fairly complex application which makes use of custom authentication middleware. I have a route group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    Route::get('/', function() {

        echo 'private';
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'public'], function() {

        Route::get('/', function() {

            echo 'public';
        });
    })
});
```

Now the `auth` middleware will redirect all requests which are not authenticated. The main group with the `auth` prefix is authenticated. However, I want the group `public` to be accessible even if the user is not authenticated.

So:

```
http://example.com/auth < must be authenticated
http://example.com/auth/some-sub-page < must be authenticated
http://example.com/auth/public < no need for authentication
```

So is there a way to add something like `'remove-middleware' => 'auth'` to the nested group with the `public` prefix? Or would I have to restructure my route groups?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wrap the auth middleware around the non-public routes?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function() {

    // routes requiring auth
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth']) {

        Route::get('/', function() {

            echo 'private';
        });

    }

    // other routes
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'public'], function() {

        Route::get('/', function() {

            echo 'public';
        });

    });
});
```

There may be a way to do a 'remove-middleware' type middleware, but that could get messy. This seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `withoutMiddleware` method on your route.

`Route::get('/example')->withoutMiddleware('auth')`

You can also use `withoutMiddleware` on `Route::group`